# Stop counting pages and printing footers after X pages

Tags: xetex, header-footer

I'm making my CV with the `europecv` package and I would like to customize one tiny detail, but I have no idea how.

Let's assume my CV is 3 pages. After these 3 pages I have 2 more pages, they are basically attachments that lists all my projects. This makes the CV with 5 pages. The footer on all 5 pages will show `Page X / 5`.

What I would like to do is to show `Page X / 3` on the first 3 pages, totally ignoring the footer on the last 2 pages. Is this possible somehow?

General document structure:

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{europecv}
    % CV pages (content)
    \newpage
    % Extra pages (attachments)
    \end{europecv}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to create two documents and use external tools like [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) to concatenate the files, but it is also possible to manually modify the `TotPages` counter (`europecv` relies on the `totpages` package) like so:

```
\documentclass[totpages]{europecv}
\usepackage{lipsum, graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{europecv}
\lipsum[1]

\end{europecv}
\lipsum 

\newpage\pagestyle{empty}
\lipsum
\addtocounter{TotPages}{-2}% <-- this must be modified manually
\end{document}
```

The main problem with this is that it is not an automatic solution, so one must pay attention to the the number of 'extra' pages one is adding to the CV.